# Develop an classic UI or be bold with a newer design?

Tags: silverlight, language-agnostic

Forgive me if this is the wrong place but I am curious as to how other programmers feel about this topic:

I am currently working on my portfolio site, it is being designed and built in silverlight 4. I initially started off with a typical stylised e-folio theme much like a standard website in terms of layout and flow.

As I work more in the concept stages something has struck me. Am I trying to shoe-horn yesterday into today? What I am talking about is UI expectations. I'm all for clean user interfaces but that does not mean they should not take advantage of new concepts in presentation right?

If you where to develop a site in silverlight as your own portfolio piece would you stick to the tried and tested "website" feel or would you try to come up with a UI that is intuitive and complements the technology?

I feel that UI discussions are all the more important now that all forms of web development are allowing better methods to engage the user.

Comment: Cheers guys, both great answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most important things in UI design is to avoid being "clever". Understand the cultural, psychological and experiential expectations of your users and *meet those expectations*, don't challenge them. If a user has to *learn* your UI concept, or an unusual mental model of information organization, you have failed.

Read [**The Design of Everyday Things**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0385267746) and [**Designing Visual Interfaces**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133033899) to dig into these ideas more deeply.

There is (very nearly) no such thing as a new UI scheme - simply new arrangements of the basic concepts of user interaction - see the iPod click wheel, for example. Almost without fail, anyone who thinks they have come up with some great new interface concept has actually just come up with crap that doesn't follow *any* of the rules of UI design - and it's bound to frustrate users, make them feel stupid, or make them think the designer is stupid.

If you understand these basic pieces, you can use new technologies like Silverlight to put them together in better ways than ever before. Again, the key is understanding them and what drives them, and **how they align with the user's conscious and unconscious needs.**

Answer (score 3):

There's two answers to this: macro and micro.

On micro level, the usual UI design idea is to NOT violate the users' expectations.
If they expect a certain type of widget/flow/look to do "X", don't make your site do "Y". It confuses or even frustrates the users.

However, you can always come up with new widgets/paradigms! (an example would be expandable panes upon introduction of JavaScript)

On a macro level, if you can come up with a new work/view/data flow or feel due to new technologies used (Silverlight), most certainly try it!

However, as usual, follow the Nielsen mantra... Hallway test!

Come up with an idea, prototype, and try it out on 5 people you know (coworkers, friends, family) to gauge usability "in real life".

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid making a Silverlight application that is the same as a web page. But were I to make a portfolio, I wouldn't put all my eggs in the Silverlight basket either. (Well unless I had the money to wait for a Silverlight job.)

I would look to embed a couple small applications made in Silverlight. Depending on what you want to emphasize, it could even be something as simple as a calculator with cool effects on the keys. Another idea is some kind of feed reader.